# Is Entity Framework programmed so it is slow when you have many entity types?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I had a model having approximately 500 entity types. Now I have added approximately 2500 entity types for future usage. Therefore now I have approximately 3000 entity types.

At this moment my program does the same as in the situation, where I had only 500 entities. My program is just building a graph of entities, i.e. instantiating a lot of entities and connecting them via references.

Unfortunately my program takes approximately 20 time longer to run as before I added the new entity types, even despite I don't deal with instances of the new entity types.

Is it correct, that there is substantial overhead in Entity Framework and it grows very significantly in the number of entities in the model, even despite the majority of the model will not be used during the lifetime of a DbContext?

Comment: EF doesn't know or care if the entities will be used, it must still initialize them. 3000 seems like a lot..

Comment: Yes, the first usage is much longer. But I only have the usages AFTER the first one on my mind. Do you have an idea, why it seems to much slower or if it's possible to enable some monitoring of what is going on, so I can get some information on this?

Comment: A major slowdown *after* everything is initialized doesn't sound right. Maybe something in this article can help you find the problem: [Performance Considerations for Entity Framework 4, 5, and 6](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

EF does a lot of reflection work at startup (which takes considerable time) over all entities defined, regardless if they are actually used or not. So if you see the startup (much) longer then it's somehow normal.

If you encounter this delay over the next queries and operations then you probably have another issue and you would need to provide more information for a solution.

Comment: Yes, the first usage is much longer. But I only have the usages AFTER the first one on my mind. Do you know of some suggestions I could look for or do you know, if Entity Framework provides some monitoring of what is going on, so I can get some information on this?

Comment: Entity Framework profiler could help -> https://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/EFProf

Comment: Also, there is http://miniprofiler.com/ which is free and it has been developed by the guys that built *StackOverflow* itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do the generate the 'EF Views' at compile-time, instead of run-time.

(not exactly sure what it is, but it is something that EF does at start-up time)

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj593170.aspx)

> Generate Views - Generates pre-compiled views used by the EF runtime to improve start-up performance.